# uint16 to float

Tags: histogram, worldview-2

I have a WorldView-2 satellite image in uint16 and the (for example) RED band histogram is  [image: histogram RED band]
ranging from 1 to 3458.
As you can see, most of the values are within ~(130-500) with very few values larger than 1000.

uint16 format raises some difficulties in visualization because usually images are expected to belong to either (0-255) or (0-1). If I want to have a float format image in the interval [0;1] how can I do it?
I tried to divide by the maximum (=3458) but clearly I get a very dark image because most of the pixel are mapped close to 0:
[image]

Instead, something similar to the image below
[image] would be better

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!